# gcloud firestore export issue (HTTP 500)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, export, gcloud

**Situation**

- I have a Firestore database with two instances, one for beta and the other one for production.
- I make sure everything works as expected in the beta instance.
- I want to export my beta instance, then I'll switch to production instance and import it back.

**Action**

- I tried to export my database using `gcloud`.

`gcloud firestore export gs://redacted --database='redacted-db-name'`

**Result**

ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.export) HttpError accessing https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/redacted/databases/redacted:exportDocuments?alt=json: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Mon, 12 Feb 2024 21:43:43 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 500}>, content <{
"error": {
"code": 500,
"message": "Internal error encountered.",
"status": "INTERNAL"
}
}

This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.

I also tried using the export method in the Google Cloud Console, but getting HTTP 500 error in there as well.